# WordPress custom post type archive-<post type>.php not working

Tags: php, wordpress, custom-post-type, permalinks

New to WordPress, I've been trying to create an archive page for a custom post type, and when I click the link to `localhost/websitename/wordpress/archive-event.php` I get a 404. Here is my code to register the post type:

```
add_action('init', 'event_register');

function event_register() {

    $labels = array(
        'name' => _x('Events', 'post type general name'),
        'singular_name' => _x('Event', 'post type singular name'),
        'add_new' => _x('Add New', 'event'),
        'add_new_item' => __('Add New Event'),
        'edit_item' => __('Edit Event'),
        'new_item' => __('New Event'),
        'view_item' => __('View Event'),
        'search_items' => __('Search Events'),
        'not_found' =>  __('Nothing found'),
        'not_found_in_trash' => __('Nothing found in Trash'),
        'parent_item_colon' => ''
    );

    $args = array(
        'labels' => $labels,
        'public' => true,
        'publicly_queryable' => true,
        'show_ui' => true,
        'query_var' => true,
        'rewrite' => array('slug' => 'event'),
        'has_archive' => 'event',
        'capability_type' => 'post',
        'hierarchical' => false,
        'menu_position' => null,
        'supports' => array('title','editor','thumbnail'),
    ); 

    register_post_type( 'event' , $args );

}
```

I've tried having `rewrite => true`, `has_archive => true`, flushing the rewrite rules, and even registering a taxonomy for the post type. `single-event.php` works fine. What now?

Comment: Do you use any specific Theme framework? Some theme-framework rewrites the usual hierarchy a bit. For example [Roots](http://www.rootstheme.com/‎)

Comment: try saving permalinks again in wp-admin panel

Comment: Done. Still doesn't work. I feel like there has to be something basic I'm doing wrong. Do I have to create taxonomies or categories for this to work? I have created an archive-event.php page by saving over the archive.php file, and I haven't made any changes. I guess I thought that it would work the same way as the single-event.php file, is this wrong?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Only two things required for custom post type archive page.

1) `has_archive` should be `true`

2) You need to flush the permalink cache once after code update.

**functions.php**

```
function my_custom_posts() {

    $labels = array(

        'name'               => _x( 'Events', 'post type general name' ),
        'singular_name'      => _x( 'Event', 'post type singular name' ),
        'add_new'            => _x( 'Add New', 'event' ),
        'add_new_item'       => __( 'Add New Event' ),
        'edit_item'          => __( 'Edit Event' ),
        'new_item'           => __( 'New Event' ),
        'all_items'          => __( 'All Events' ),
        'view_item'          => __( 'View Event' ),
        'search_items'       => __( 'Search Events' ),
        'not_found'          => __( 'No events found' ),
        'not_found_in_trash' => __( 'No events found in the Trash' ), 
        'parent_item_colon'  => '',
        'menu_name'          => 'Events'

    );

    $args = array(

        'labels'        => $labels,
        'description'   => 'Holds our events and event specific data',
        'public'        => true,
        'menu_position' => 5,
        'supports'      => array( 'title' ),
        'has_archive'   => true, // only this is required to enable archive page else 404 error will occur
        'publicly_queryable' => true,
        'show_ui' => true,
        'query_var' => true,
        'rewrite' => array('slug' => 'events', 'with_front' => true),
        'capability_type' => 'post',
        'hierarchical' => false,

    );

    register_post_type( 'event', $args );   
    //flush_rewrite_rules();

}

add_action( 'init', 'my_custom_posts' );
```

Default `archive.php` will work but if you wish to overwrite default one, you have to use a proper archive template `archive-<custom_post_slug>.php`, e.g.

```
archive-events.php
```

Also, if you're just registering your post type, you will need to flush the permalink cache. Do this by changing permalink structure in to Wordpress admin.

Now you can access archive page https://domain/post_slug/

**Note:** if you choose `Numeric` in permalink structure url would be https://domain/archives/post_slug/

Answer (score 4):

not sure this will answer your question but did you reset your permalink structure?

If you just added a custom post type, you will need go to Permalinks page and press Save.

Hope that helps!

Comment: Best answer. Worked perfectly for me! I was struggling with that for hours!

Answer (score 1):

I was using **CPT UI** plugin where "Has Archive" flag was set to False by default.
You can change this in:

```
"Edit Post Type" tab > "Settings" > "Has Archive"
```

set it to True, instead and don't forget to flush Permalinks (click Save on Permalinks page).

Answer (score 0):

It looks like in your URL example you're attempting to get to the actual template file name itself.

But if you've defined the slug to be `event` you should be able to simply visit localhost/websitename/wordpress/event

Comment: I'm afraid that url doesn't work either. I've also tried leaving the slug as the default, and setting rewrite => true, which doesn't help either.

Comment: @user2280983 Did you ever find a solution to this? I'm having the same issue as you!

Comment: @Michael Giovanni Pumo Not really, I just ended up directing my archive links to "http://localhost/sitename/wordpress/?post_type=event". Not very pretty, but it seems to work if all you want to do is to display a list of a certain post type.

Comment: @user2280983 I have submit a new answer to this question based on my finding since. Seems to work well for me! Have a look and if it helps answer your question, that'd be great. Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

There is issue in **Permalink structure**. I have change settings => my Permalink to "Day and name" or "Month and name" or "Post name" which has fixed my issue.